# How do I stop XFCE4 from respawing programms running at logout on login?

Tags: login, xubuntu

I disabled the checkbox "Save Session automatically" in Preferences => Session. Still all the programms start but I don't want them to.

Oh, strange thing: The Windowmanager does not start. I've got to log in at the console and enter DISPLAY=:0.0 xfwm4. It's somthing new, but I guess it has a common error source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i tried is remove everything from ~/.cache/sessions

try:

> rm -rf ~/.cache/sessions

Comment: also fixed the wm issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try saving a completely empty session? That is, you close everything you started, and then quit xfce while the checkbox is checked.

I wonder if it would solve your problem or it will refuse to overwrite the existing session if it would become empty.

edit:

Googling "xfce session file" yielded two promising results at the top.

1. [Xfce file locations](http://foo-projects.org/~benny/xfce/file-locations.html) describes the location of the files used by xfce, including the session.
2. [Xfce Wiki - faq](http://wiki.xfce.org/faq#session_manager) describes your exact problem.

Comment: No, It's not always the same programm, it's exacly the same running when login off. Even the Windows-Manager, once run will be used in the next session. I'll try and make the session dirs read only.